# My navigation bar is not responsive when opened on a phone, I have tried to use the burger menu but its on working

Tags: responsive, hamburger-menu

I want to create a responsive navigation bar that the responsive when opened on a phone. I am trying to implement a Burger Menu. I have added the code for a burger menu in my html, css and js code but its not working.

Here is my part of the code relating to the navigation bar

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Home </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon"    href="Favicon/favicon.ico"/>
    
   </head>
   <body>
        <header>
         <h1>Tallinn University HCI Hub</h1>
        <p>Connecting the World of Human-Computer Interaction</p>
    </header>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="burger-menu" onclick="toggleMenu()">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="nav-links">

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="speakers.html">Speakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="meme.html">UniMeme Mingles</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">UniStyle Event Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
   .burger-menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
}

   .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

    .burger-menu {
    display: flex;
}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-links {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #333;
        z-index: 1;
    }


    nav {
    background-color: #34495e; 
    color: #ecf0f1;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

    nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

    nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
```

//index page

```
toggleMenu() {
var navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
navLinks.style.display = (navLinks.style.display === 'flex') ? 'none' : 'flex';
```

}`

I tried to use the burger menu so that my naviagtion bar is more responsive. But my code for the
burger menu seems not to be working. How can i fix this  and have the burger menu function or work well.